# digitalocean api : get droplets without tag name

Tags: linux, bash, digital-ocean

How can I get droplets without having tag-name using cli reference?

```
doctl compute droplet list --tag-name "what should be provided here"
```

Tried:

```
doctl compute droplet list --tag-name ""

doctl compute droplet list --tag-name ''
```

Answer (score 0):

I think (haven't tried) that you can't test for the absence of a tag.

[`doctl compute droplet list`](https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/doctl/reference/compute/droplet/list/) only accepts a single `--tag_name` and so I assume (!?) the (server) implementation filters the list of Droplets by those that **include** the tag value.

What you may (!?) be able to do is to list everything as JSON and then post-filter the results for those with empty (`[]`) tags.

Comment: Just for reference, in Powershell you can do this by
` doctl compute droplet list -o json|ConvertFrom-JSON|Where-Object -Not tags`